# In Implementing an Extension on a Measurement, can we use a Generic for UnitType?

Tags: swift, generics

Essentially, I want to have a function on Measurement that rounds the value to a certain number of places. I already have that function written fo Double, so I tried this for Measurement:

```
extension Measurement {
    func roundToPlace<T>(_ place: Int) -> Measurement<T> {
        return Measurement(value: self.value.roundToPlace(place), unit: self.unit)
    }
}

extension Double {
    func roundToPlace(_ place: Int) -> Double {
        let rounder = Double(truncating: pow(10, place) as NSNumber)
        
        return (Double(Int(self * rounder)) / rounder)
    }
}
```

I would like this to work on all UnitTypes, as nothing is being changed with the UnitType. I thought setting the UnitType to be a Generic would allow me to simply pass it back, but the compiler is throwing the following error:

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Measurement<UnitType>' to return type 'Measurement<T>'`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why didn't you post the Double extension?

Comment: I updated it, but it really has no effect on the question.

Comment: I see. It's just named wrong. (`round` instead of `rounded`.)

Comment: Instead of rounding the value you should use MeasurementFormatter and round the numberformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the existing `UnitType` generic type from within the `Measurement` type and make it the return value. There is no point in making the function generic, since the `Measurement` itself is already generic.

```swift
extension Measurement {
    func roundToPlace(_ place: Int) -> Measurement<UnitType> {
        return Measurement(value: self.value.roundToPlace(place), unit: self.unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. A generic UnitType so that I could return a new Measurement.

Comment: The code here isn't generic. It's just being very explicit about the return type. `Measurement<UnitType>` is identical to `Self` in this case.

Comment: @RobNapier I came here to comment this :)

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier and Leo for these comments. I just want to be sure what am I missing here about the code being generic. I know I explicitly state `Measurement` type but since the `UnitType` is a placeholder type, it's the final result equal to what we would achieve by using `Self`?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the type of returned value is the same in both cases since the `Measurement.UnitType == Self.UnitType`

Comment: Correct. This function is not generic in that you're not passing any type parameters. It's just a normal function on a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat suspicious of your `roundToPlace` function. Most attempts to implement this aren't going to do what most people mean due to binary rounding. But it is possible to round to "the power of two that is closest to this power of ten," so maybe that's what you mean. (I've built that myself, and it's fine. It just bites people when they think they can print out the value and it won't have ...0000000004 at the end :D)

To your actual question, your code allows the caller to decide what the UnitType is, and you promise to return that type, no matter what the existing UnitType is. That's not what you mean. You mean "return the same type as the current measurement." That's not generic at all. It just returns `Self` (which is the type of `self`).

```
extension Measurement {
    func roundToPlace(_ place: Int) -> Self {
        return Self(value: self.value.roundToPlace(place), unit: self.unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work, though I wanted a new Measurement, not to change self.

Comment: You're thinking of `self` which is an instance. `Self` is the type of `self`.

Comment: @Yrb, it does return a new measurement. `Self(...)` inits a new measurement of the same type as current one

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, I was thinking of self, not Self. Both answers do return the proper UnitType... And, if fact, you can mix and match and it works, returning a `return Measurement(value: self.value.roundToPlace(place), unit: self.unit)'

Comment: or simply `.init(value...`

Comment: `Measurement` is a struct, so yes, you actually do want a mutated copy of `self`. Not doing that introduces the useless copying of `unit`, and that will extend to everything else that requires copying. It's a bad pattern. Copying, mutating, and then returning, is the best pattern the language offers.

Comment: @jessy Making a copy of Measurement would make the same copy of `unit` (copying a struct copies all its members). Copy/mutate/return is a fine pattern, but in this case is more code and I expect a bit less obvious (because unfortunately Swift does not make it clear whether a type is a value type or a reference type, so when you see "copy/mutate" you often need to double-check). But either way would be fine and equivalent in the number of copies (at least prior to optimization; after optimization, it would depend much more on the internals; Measurement is an ObjC overlay, not a simple struct).